# ValueError: could not convert string to float error

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code that I want to create a line chart from:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(csv2)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

start_date = '2005-01-01'
end_date = '2014-12-31'

mask = (df['Date'] > start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date) 
df = df.loc[mask].sort_values('Date')
df['Data_Value'] = df['Data_Value']/10
df['Month_Day'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')

# Sort Max
tmax = df[df['Element'] =='TMAX'] 
tmax = tmax.loc[tmax.groupby("Month_Day")["Data_Value"].idxmax()]
tmax = tmax[['Month_Day','Data_Value']]
tmax = tmax.set_index('Month_Day').astype(np.float64)
```

So far I'm just attempting a simple line chart:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(tmax)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '12-31'
```

The "12-31" value is present in the "Month_Day" column, which I have attempted to convert to float. However, the error message remains.

Have also seen post regarding timestamps etc, but not sure how to apply it.

Comment: Obviously you can't convert `12-31` into float. It has a hypen `-`. What do you want it to look like?

Comment: "The "12-31" value is present in the "Month_Day" column, which I have attempted to convert to float." In your own words: What is a `float`? Why do you think it should be possible to convert the string `"12-31"` to float? What value do you expect to get as a result? Especially considering the fact that the column is labelled `"Month_Day"`, what single numeric value makes sense here? What exactly do you want on the X and Y axes of your graph?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Basically I want the X axis to be "Month_Day" and Y axis to be "Data_Value"

Comment: Bascially, just removed the hyphen from "Date", now it produces a plot.Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean for "the X axis to be `Month_Day`"? The values in `Month_Day` represent a month and day of the year, correct? But you want a *single* numeric value for the X axis, right? Am I correct that you want the days of the year to be evenly spaced out? Then perhaps you need a mathematical rule that translates a (month, day) pair into, I don't know, a number of days since the beginning of the year? Something like that?